# Homemade ethernet cable not wprking

Tags: laptop

Hi I made my own Ethernet cable using the cat 5e cable and rj45 plugs I had finish trace the cable from one end of the house to the other end after I finished I put the rj45 plugs in and uses a normal plyers to crimp the plug since I did not have a crimping tool and now when I connect my computer to the cable its not working and it doesn't even pick up I don't know what to ddo

Comment: Using pliers probably wont be enough to force the contacts to cut into the wires. Use the right tools for the job.

Comment: Borrow the proper pliers and make sure you get the wires in the correct places : paired and coded...

Comment: So the cat5e cable is not the problem then , the problem is with the rj45 plugs if I purchase new plugs will the Ethernet cable work or will I still have the same problem of the cable not working

Comment: Impossible for us to predict if it will work.  You need to get the correct tool to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

You have a combination of problems. As stated you have to have a pair of crimpers, the jacks have tiny pieces of metal that need to be pushed into the cable. You cannot do this with pliers.

The second issue is that there are wiring standards, the pairs and wires need to be inserted into the jacks in a certain order – pairs *must not* be split. (For example, the middle pins must be paired 3-6 and 4-5.) Otherwise the signal quality will degrade.

[image: Ethernet A Standard]

This is an example of the T568A standard. (Another popular one, T568B swaps the colors around, but the pairings remain the same.)